# Incorrect font color of enumerate list inside tcbtheorem when using beamer's colors

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I am creating a `tcbtheorem` with colors taken from beamer's `block` environment. For some reason, color of lists is unexpectedly `coltitle` instead of `coltext`. How can I sort this issue?

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{mythm}{My Theorem}{%
    code={\usebeamercolor{block title}},
    colback=gray!5,
    coltext=black,
    colbacktitle=bg,
    coltitle=fg,
    size=fbox,
}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{mythm}{}{}
            Text
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item List
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{mythm}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how the enumerate list font color is not black, but blue (same as the title foreground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when writing https://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox . My workaround looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!5,fg=black}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\beamer@tcb@colini}[1][]{
  \usebeamercolor{block body#1} 
  \colorlet{beamer@tcb@bodybg}{block body#1.bg}
  \colorlet{beamer@tcb@bodyfg}{block body#1.fg}
  \usebeamercolor{block title#1} 
  \colorlet{beamer@tcb@titlebg}{block title#1.bg}
  \colorlet{beamer@tcb@titlefg}{block title#1.fg}  
  \usebeamercolor{normal text}
}

\newtcbtheorem{mythm}{My Theorem}{%
    code={\beamer@tcb@colini},
    colback=beamer@tcb@bodybg,
    colbacktitle=beamer@tcb@titlebg,
    coltext=beamer@tcb@bodyfg,
    coltitle=beamer@tcb@titlefg,
    before title={\usebeamerfont{block title}},
    before upper={\usebeamercolor{block body}\usebeamerfont{block body}},
    size=fbox,
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{mythm}{}{}
            Text
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item List
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{mythm}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As this problem has already been solved in the tcolorbox inner theme, you could also use this theme instead if redefining the theorems yourself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!5,fg=black}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  size=fbox,
  boxrule=1pt,
  borderline={1pt}{0pt}{gray},
  titlerule=1pt,
  titlerule style=gray 
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{theorem}
            Text
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item List
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]